# Versioneye and phpunit dependencies

Tags: php, github, phpunit, composer-php

Versioneye is a good way to track dependencies, I enjoy using it, however I've run into an issue:

My repository is for php 5.4 and greater which means I must use phpunit ~4.8

Versioneye however says my dependency for phpunit is outdated because 5.1.* is the latest, but you cannot run phpunit 5 on anything less than php 5.6.

**Is there a way to specify in composer or anywhere else that on php 5.4/5.5 phpunit 4.8 should be used and on php 5.6 phpunit 5.1.* should be used?**

***Or do I simply go into versioneye and tell it not to consider 5.1.17 at all? But then I have to constantly keep that up-to-date.***

Thanks for your help in advance, here are the git repo and version eye links:

https://github.com/thephpeffect/TriggrPHP
https://www.versioneye.com/user/projects/56b3ba5e0a0ff5002c85ed7b?child=summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the PHP version in `composer.json` it should update only the dependency to versions that are admitted in PHP 5.4. This would prevent the outdated libraries message, and you shouldn't need to care anymore:

```
  "config" : {
     "platform": {
        "php": "5.4"
     }
  }
```

But AFAIK there is no way of choosing the version depending on the installed PHP version.

Comment: Ok, so i just have to let it error or be more specific, but being more specific means some couldn't install with composer when they should be able to. Oh well. Thanks

Comment: Everyone will be able to install. This is just for composer to think PHP 5.4 is installed regarding on the real version, so everyone will get the dependency versions supported by 5.4, but not the latest.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I used

"phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8|~5.1"

it automatically detects that 5.1 is an option regardless of php version and shows dependencies as up-to-date.